# How to read empty XML elements?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<address>111 North Bridge Road </address>
```

Hi,

I have a XML file with many tags like the above. 
I'm using javascript that read the file and use document.write to write contents of the element.

However everytime it reads an empty element, it stops writing .

Is there anyway to check for an empty element using javascript?

Comment: Can you give us some sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

An empty element doesn't have childNodes, so you could check

```
element.childNodes.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasChildNodes()` which returns a boolean

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).